# Using qmake to generate a makefile that has FLTK fluild files?

Tags: qmake, fltk

I was wondering if anyone might have an idea how 
to use qmake to generate a program that has 
FLTK fluid files ?

I have foo.fl that generate fl.cxx and fl.hxx which get compiled.
I don't know how or if it is even possible to get qmake to do this pre-processing step
as well as add the sources to the list that needs to be compiled.

I was hoping someone might have a suggestion.

Thanks,
Danny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use the qmake variable `QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS`.  See [QMake's Documentation on Configuring Its Environment](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmake-environment-reference.html) for more details.